# OPENSHFITRHOCS LDAP INTEGRATION

Tags: openshift

We are using openshift RHOCS cluster ,  as per the red hat only core user will only available to login to the cluster . we are planning to integrate our ldap sever to rhel core os servers to we can login with our organization user id  and that helps  to monitor .

1. Is it best practice use to ldap user instead of  default (core) user  ?
   2)Pls suggest the best practices ?
2. Is there any documents that help us ?